# How split one huge service configuration file into several bundle configuration files

Tags: php, symfony, dependencies

I am trying to split one huge monolithic Symfony2 service configuration file into several smaller files and group them by functionality, etc.

My code:

```
- app/config/config.yml:

imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: "@YYYCarPartsBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml" }    
    - { resource: "@XXXShopsBundle/Resources/config/parameters.yml" }   
    ...
    - { resource: "@YYYCarPartsBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
    - { resource: "@XXXShopsBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }         


- YYYCarPartsBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

services:
    car.parts.provider:
        class: YYY\Services\Parts\Provider\Factory
        arguments:
            - .........
            - .........


- XXXShopsBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    xxx.webservice.client.find.model:
        class: XXX\Soap\ExtendedSoapClient
        arguments:
            - .........
            - "@car.parts.provider"
```

Unfortunately I am getting this error
Fatal error: Uncaught exception

> 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException'
>   with message 'The service "xxx.webservice.client.find.model" has a
>   dependency on a non-existent service "car.parts.provider".' in
>   vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php
>   on line 59

I thought container will import all resource files in order, but it does not look like. 
I am using Symfony 2.3.7. I have tried to define xxx.webservice.client.find.model as lazy service, but no effects.

Any help, explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can define services per bundle in in the `Resources/config` directories *without* having to explicitly import them, and pretty sure you can use yaml or xml (i.e., `src/XXX/ShopsBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`)

Comment: Thanks for info how Symfony loads configuration files from bundles. Regarding my problem it was PEBCAK - wrong indentation in one file so car.parts.provider was really missing.